# npm says I have unmet request dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the express module: `npm install -g express`

The output shows:

```
root@Rx:~/node-v0.10.36# npm install -g express
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/couch-login requires request@'~2.9.202' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.42.0
express@4.11.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── methods@1.1.1
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── finalhandler@0.3.3
├── vary@1.0.0
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── serve-static@1.8.1
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@1.0.0
├── qs@2.3.3
├── on-finished@2.2.0 (ee-first@1.1.0)
├── debug@2.1.1 (ms@0.6.2)
├── etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.5 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.6)
├── send@0.11.1 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.7.0, mime@1.2.11)
├── accepts@1.2.3 (negotiator@0.5.0, mime-types@2.0.8)
└── type-is@1.5.6 (mime-types@2.0.8)
```

In fact it says this whenever I install things with `-g`

I tried `npm install request` and it seems successful but didn't fix the issue, so I tried `npm install -g request` with the same unmet dependency error.

This is a freshly compiled version of npm and nodejs from the official site. Running latest debian.
What's wrong here?

Comment: Try clearing the npm cache by `npm cache clear`, remove all npm packages then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure why this worked or which command did it but I ran these and it started working:

`npm install -g npm`
`npm update` `npm update -g`

I got the same dependency errors while I ran some of those so I'm not sure which fixed it but after trying to install express again, there were no errors.